# How to validate user input in Java FX?

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I'm a little bit confused because I'm looking for the right way to validate user input in **Java FX** but all I find is validating each field by myself.

I'm using Spring boot, [spring-boot-javafx library](https://www.felixroske.de/page/programmierung/index.html) with Java Fx and it's hard to believe that in 2018 with all the tools we have (hibernate validator?) I have to validate each field by myself :)

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I used ControlsFX' validation for a JavaFX project, and it's quite handy.
http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/ - Decoration/Validation

https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/validation/ValidationSupport.html

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer :) I've seen this library but I'm having issues with it (NPE in javafx component, non in my code + design problem) so as I don't really have the choixe I'll make the validation by myself ....